# AWS Fargate clusters stop logging shortly after being started up, although still being healthy and running

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

We have a blue/green deployment in AWS using Fargate.
In this deploy we run 2 tasks. They are being started and healthy and we see the first logs, in the ECS tasks themselves and in Cloudwatch. After some minutes though, we don't get any new log messages in either one anymore.
The instances though keep on running and all looks like normal.

I found this post here that describes a very similar issue, but does not have any answers yet: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=987634&tstart=0

Anybody experienced something similar or can advice where to check for possible causes?

Comment: Is your task use two or more container images?

Comment: It's one image, that we are running in two tasks. So two containers with the same image.

Comment: Is java or some language based? or Nginx, etc. software based logs?

Comment: The code is written in nodeJS using Winston Logger to log to CloudWatch. The machines are EC2's.